# Avoid webfont download when it exists locally

Tags: html, css, webfonts

How can I avoid dynamically loading a webfont (e.g. Mylius Modern) from a website when it already exists on the local machine?

Comment: Do you have that font still on file? I have a version of it given to me by BA for one of their sites, but I can't convert it as it's .pfb and .afm format.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `local()` source in your webfont's `@font-face` block:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Mylius Modern;
    src: local('Mylius Modern') …;
}
```

However, it *may* cause permission problems.

(The … is where you should put the rest of the sources, like you're probably doing already, separated with a comma. For Internet Explorer support, however: make sure to put a `src` containing an Embedded OpenType (`.eot`) font *before* the `src` containing the `local()`, as IE8 and earlier don't recognize it.)

Comment: +1, But You might want to specify the fallback to download as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

for other website you can do nothing . but if you want to do this in your website than k the css3 can help you

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Mylius Modern;
  src: local(Mylius Modern),   /* use locally available Mylius Modern*/
       url(Mylius_Modern.ttf); /* otherwise, download it */
}
```